# Configure VPN to allow MMS

Tags: android, openvpn

I recently installed Pi-Hole + PiVPN (OpenVPN) on a RPI at my home. I used [this guide](https://marcstan.net/blog/2017/06/25/PiVPN-and-Pi-hole/) to set it up and it works great, traffic from the VPN is routed thru the Pi-Hole; however when connected to the VPN via my Pixel 2 with the OpenVPN Connect app I cannot send or receive MMS messages. I have tried disabling the Pi-Hole to determine if the problem is with the VPN or Pi-Hole and the problem persists.

I am hoping someone knows how I can adjust my OpenVPN configuration so that I can send and receive text messages while connected to my VPN. My OpenVPN server.config is as follows:

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server_2wA4OjM7gfFQzARq.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server_2wA4OjM7gfFQzARq.key
dh none
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
#push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
#push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
# Prevent DNS leaks on Windows
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
keepalive 1800 3600
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device.
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
# User changes below
# Set localhost for DNS so it gets routed thru pi-hole
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
```

Comment: You will find two excellent tutorials in [article1](https://blogs.perficient.com/2017/09/12/how-to-connect-your-android-phone-to-your-aws-based-vpn-server/) or in [article2](https://forum.xda-developers.com/raspberry-pi/general/pi-hole-pivpn-powered-raspberry-pi-3-t3768983). Check what you did against these two.

Comment: Hi @harrymc, sorry for the delayed response; I have looked thru your guides and I have things set up more or less as described across the two, the main differences being that I am not using a recursive dns setup because authoritative dns is fine for my purposes. I should note that I am able to connect to and use the open vpn successfully, it is just that texting doesn't seem to work. I have done some research and seen that google's sms replacement, RCS, may use ipv6 in some capacity, and my vpn isnt set up for v6 explicitly so maybe that is a problem?

Comment: Maybe, if the app uses IPv4.